# Как при переходе на Activity c BottomNavigationView сразу открыть первый fragment?

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

При переходе на MyActivity выбирается первая иконка, но отображается пустая страница, и лишь по нажатию на иконку отображается нужный fragment. Как сделать чтобы fragment отображался сразу при переходе на MyActivity?

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        bottomNavigation =(BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_nav);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.action_profil:
                        fragment = new ProfilFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_shop:
                        fragment = new ShopFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_mail:
                        fragment = new MailFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_book:
                        fragment = new BookFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_settings:
                        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                        break;
                }
                final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто нужно явно отобразить первый фрагмент при открытии активити. Добавьте следующий код в конец метода `onCreate`:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.main_container, new ProfilFragment())
        .commit();
```